# Aloe vera plant has rot deep in the leaf, and is looking wilted

Tags: diseases, indoors, succulents, aloe, rot

I've had this plant for several years. Last summer I replanted it. It seems to have significantly wilted over the past few months. The leaves used to reach for the sky. A healthy leaf had fallen out by itself and now I'm seeing a large black spot close to the base of the leaves with white mold growing on it.

Am I watering the plant too much? Should I give it medicine? Should I cut off the rotten part?

[image]
[image]

Here are some photos taken a few weeks ago

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like soft rot, which is a bacteria.  Most experts say it is difficult to control but you can try several things:

1. Reduce watering
2. Prune away the affected parts
3. Repot it using new soil (sounds like you recently did this so maybe try the other two)