# How high to the top of the pot should plant be?

Tags: indoors, aloe

I had asked the question [Aloe vera plant has rot deep in the leaf, and is looking wilted](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/61625/aloe-vera-plant-has-rot-deep-in-the-leaf-and-is-looking-wilted)

I think when I re-potted it, I didn't put enough dirt in and the level of the plant may be too low. Would it help if I added more dirt? Should I take the whole plant out to add more dirt to the bottom of the pot or can I just add more dirt to the top layer?

Answer (score 1):

Simply cover the roots with soil, just like the plant would grow in the wild. Leave the stems / leaves out. The more substrate you give the roots, the healthier the plant will be, since it will have room for root development. To answer your question, leave maybe 2 cm (one inch) of space between the top of the pot and the soil you put in.

In the case of your Aloe, make sure to water the pot very seldomly (perhaps once a month, even less in wintertime). It's much easier to kill a plant from overabundance of water than from lack of it.